# Matrix transforming with translation/rotation/scale at center of screen

Tags: xna, rotation, monogame, matrix, transformation

I'm trying to create a camera using matrix transforms, the gist is as follows:

```
Transform =
     Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
     Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0)) *
     Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
     Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Bounds.Width * 0.5f, Bounds.Height * 0.5f, 0));
```

It works but with one issue. The rotation origin remains at the starting (-Position.X, -Position.Y) while the zoom works fine (at the center screen) which is obvious from the code. I'd like the rotation to occur at the center screen as well.

Comment: Hey Avagantamo, could you provide more code? Because currently, it's not sure what values the `Rotation`, `Position`, `Zoom` and `Bounds` are.

Comment: Hi @Steven . The code is from this link https://community.monogame.net/t/simple-2d-camera/9135 with an extra property (Rotation) similar to how the Zoom works in it. The above code is an altered version from the UpdateMatrix() method for including the rotation